# Can one use a list to find a collection of rows in a query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list

I have a list of strings, provided from an earlier query. This strings are identifiers in this first table, lets call this table1, and exist in another column, inside another datatable, call this table2. I want to use the list directly inside a query attempting to fetch all the rows from table2 containing these any of the identifier in list.

Is this possible? I have been reading into the .Any() function, though I have yet to come up with a solution using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like:

```
List<string> firstList = .....;
var query = dataTable2.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(r => firstList.Contains(r.Field<string>("IdColumn")));
```

Comment: Would r.'FieldName', be enough? Given that the field in question is already stored as a string, or does the Contains() require that the lambda be declared through use of Field<type>("ColumnName")?

Comment: `Field<type>` because it is a `DataTable` and Field is an extension method on `DataRow`, but if it LINQ to SQL / LINQ To Entity it would be like `.Where(r=> firstList.Contains(r.IdColumn))`

Comment: Ah alright, that makes sense. Thank you very much Habib.